# Why was the LONG RAW Oracle column type deprecated in ORACLE 8?

Tags: oracle

Why was the LONG RAW ORACLE column type deprecated in ORACLE 8 ?

Did Oracle have issues with its implementation ?

Answer (score 2):

Lots of reasons mentioned here:

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=2&f=59&t=107157

Reasons include performance and lack of functionality with LONG RAW.